# Dynamic Xml Modification

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am working on a project that demands dynamic modification of xml files, which mostly involves adding new entries(elements /nodes) into the files.

However, there are the following considerations:

1. It should be possible to add a new element at a specific position (and not just append).
2. The prologue, comments and format of the file should remain intact after the modification.
3. Unnecessary escaping of characters should not be performed.

I have tried using JAXB, XML Startlet and Eclipse Epsilon EOL, but there have been some problems with these.

**JAXB** did work to a large extent except for the unwanted escaping of characters it performs, but I need something apart from java.

With **XmlStartlet**, it is possible to stop the escaping but the problem is that, it only appends new elements.

Consider:

**xyz.xml**

```
<school>
<student no="1"/>
<student no="2"/>
<teacher no="t1"/>
<teacher no="t2"/>
..
..
</school>
```

Now, the command

```
xml ed -s /school -t elem -n "student" xyz.xml
```

appends `student` at the end:

```
<school>
<student no="1"/>
<student no="2"/>
<!--New student should be added here!!-->
<teacher no="t1"/>
<teacher no="t2"/>
..
..
<student/>
</school>
```

With **Epsilon Eols**, it is also not possible to add nodes at the proper position (it too appends) and further, it *escapes* the double quotes within a string to """ (as does JAXB)

Eg:

```
<student id ="123" status='query.isdaysScholar("123")/>
```

After running the EOL, this appears:

```
<student id ="123" status="query.isdayscholar(&quot;123&quot;)/>
```

Is there any other parser or an XML scripting/quering language which can allow me to modify the XML document along with providing the above said features?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) using a more specific [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression, like:

```
xmlstarlet ed --omit-decl -a '/school/student[@no="2"]' -t elem -n "student" xmlfile
```

to add a new student after the last one. It yields:

```
<school>
  <student no="1"/>
  <student no="2"/>
  <student/>
  <teacher no="t1"/>
  <teacher no="t2"/>
</school>
```

Also you can insert it just before first `<teacher>` element, like:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
    --omit-decl \
    -i '/school/teacher[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::student]]' \
    -t elem \
    -n "student" \
xmlfile
```

that yields same result:

```
<school>
  <student no="1"/>
  <student no="2"/>
  <student/>
  <teacher no="t1"/>
  <teacher no="t2"/>
</school>
```